# Remove server (that no longer exists) from 2010 farm?

Tags: 2010, administration, server-farm

I had a virtual server we'll call spTest. It had to be rebuilt, so someone renamed it spTst and created a new virtual server they named spTest. Then they deleted spTst.

SpTest seems to be working, I can navigate to my content, etc.

BUT... SharePoint Health Analyzer is listing spTst as a failing server on several error messages.

These errors are listed with SpTst as the failing server, and were true (SpTest did have an account on the local machine admins, it was running out of space, and there was no state service configured.):

- Accounts used by application pools or service identities are in the local machine Administrators group.
- InfoPath Forms Services forms cannot be filled out in a Web browser because no State Service connection is configured.
- Drives are running out of free space.

Here's the other errors listed:

- One or more services have started or stopped unexpectedly. (SPTimerService (SPTimerV4) on SpTest) The Reanalyze and Repair Automatically links are grayed out.
- The Application Discovery and Load Balancer Service is not running in this farm. (No failing server listed, but there is no Proxy for this service at Central Admin - > Application Management - > Manage Service Applications. Application Discovery and Load Balancer Service Application has a status of Started.)

I believe both of these are either caused by (or I'm on unable to resolve because of) SharePoint thinking there are 2 web front end servers. So I think I need to remove SpTst from SharePoint. But how?

According to Microsoft:

> If a Web or application server is no longer available, or if
>   uninstalling SharePoint Server 2010 from Control Panel is not
>   possible, you can remove the Web server or application server from the
>   farm by using the SharePoint Central Administration Web site.

When I open Central Administration - > System Settings - > Manage Servers in this farm, the server is not listed. The only servers listed are the database server and mail server. (If SpTest isn't listed, I wonder why SpTst would be.)

When I try to run SharePoint Products Configuration Wizard, I get this error:

> Failed to detect if this server is joined to a server farm.  Possible
>   reasons for this failure could be that you no longer have the
>   appropriate permissions to the server farm, the database server
>   hosting the server farm is unresponsive, the configuration database is
>   inaccessible or this server has been removed from the server farm.  To
>   diagnose this problem further, review the extended error information
>   located at C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server
>   Extensions\14\LOGS\PSCDiagnostics_6_21_2012_13_53_55_37_451280392.log.
>   If this problem persists, choose to disconnect from the server farm. 
>   After disconnecting, run the wizard again to create or connect to an
>   existing server farm.

The error log:

> 06/21/2012 13:54:00  1  INF          SPFarm.Local retuned a farm, but
>   SPServer.Local returned null.  Failed to connect to the farm, except
>   in B2B Upgrade.
>
> 06/21/2012 13:54:00  1  ERR        Failed to successfully try to see
>   if this server is joined to the server farm.  The operation will
>   continue so that you can force a disconnect from a server farm that
>   cannot be contacted

It presents me with an option to remove from farm.

> If you choose to continue, this computer will no longer host the
>   SharePoint Central Administration Web Application (if one exists) and
>   will be immediately removed from this server farm.  To join another
>   server farm after disconnecting, run this configuration wizard again. 
>   Do you want to continue?

So this doesn't seem to be the solution, because SpTest is hosting Central Admin.

I restarted, did not seem to change anything.

How can I remove this non-existent server?

UPDATE: Since I haven't gotten any responses, I asked a summary of the same question here: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010setup/thread/7654dec6-78c8-447a-859e-8f3736916e6d

UPDATE 2: Get-SPServer returns the mail server and the database server. (Same servers that show up under Central Administration - > System Settings - > Manage Servers.)

Comment: You've started a SharePoint.SE vs. MS Forums race to the answer! Who will win? ONLY TIME WILL TELL.

Comment: If you use Get-SPServer (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607694.aspx) does it get listed?